# fail to follow on instagram

Tags: jquery, url, instagram

I am using following code to follow users on instagram. It run successfully and send code 200 with none status. it is not follow successfully. please tell me what is the problem and what should I do?

```
var followurl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + userid + "/relationship";

         var status="follow";
    $.ajax({
        url: followurl,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: { access_token:accesstoken, action:status},
        success: function (result) {

            alert(result.meta.code);
            alert(result.data.outgoing_status);                
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you got a HTTP 200 doesn't mean that the operation was successful. What it means is that the server got it and served a response. Use a tool like firebug or chrome developer tools and set break point in the success callback. Check the result object, it might contain a message saying why it was unsuccessful.